# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl':

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations

I am getting following error while trying to configure beans annotation way. Is there any need to declare bean SessionFactory in my-servlet.xml file ? I am confused why its needed if I am using annotations.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProces
```

**my-servlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Source project: sip03, branch: 01 (Maven Project) -->
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    ">
    <!--  <context:annotation-config/> -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring" />    
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

<tx:annotation-driven /> 
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

    </beans>
```

**UserDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.spring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.spring.model.Users;

@Component
public class UserDaoImpl implements UsersDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public UserDaoImpl() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public UserDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Users> list() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Users> listUser = (List<Users>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(Users.class)
                .list();
        System.out.println(" size : " + listUser.size());

        return listUser;
    }
}
```

**DemoController.java**

```
package com.spring.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl;
import com.spring.dao.UsersDao;
import com.spring.model.Users;

@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    private UsersDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String demoIndex() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/list")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        List<Users> listUsers = userDao.list();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("list");
        model.addObject("userList", listUsers);
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you think the `SessionFactory` should come from? Why do you think so?

Comment: Its annotation way, still we need to configure SessionFactory, DataSource, TrasactionManager ?

Comment: What do you mean by _its annotation way_?

Comment: annotation way of configuring beans

Comment: I repeat. Where do you declare a `SessionFactory` bean? Where do you think Spring finds objects to inject?

Comment: I just added SessionFactory, DataSource, TrasactionManager beans in my-servlet.xml and exception gone. Please have a look at my-servlet.xml , am I doing it right way ?

Comment: But now data is not coming, List is empty. I am sure data is there in database, Please help me out

Comment: First thing: get rid of xml's. Read about configuration using only annotation an implement those. Second, what did you do to make it work? Give a brief explanation so others can he helped from your answer